# How do you do obstacle avoidance with MoveIt?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm just getting started with ROS / MoveIt.

Let's say you have a robot arm, and that there will always be an S-shaped object that a robot arm should move around. What should you do so that the robot arm navigate around this object?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366839/how-do-you-do-obstacle-avoidance-with-moveit?/) by [galaxee](https://answers.ros.org/users/64484/galaxee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could add the object to the URDF. [See here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Adding%20Physical%20and%20Collision%20Properties%20to%20a%20URDF%20Model). That's what I would recommend since it will always be there.

OR, in code, you could set up a Planning Scene and add the S-shaped collision object to it. There's a tutorial [here](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene_ros_api/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html#attach-an-object-to-the-robot). The message definition is [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/CollisionObject.html).

OR you can add the collision mesh with the RViz MotionPlanning plugin (GUI). Of course, then you would have to re-add the object manually every time you launch the robot.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2020-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [galaxee](https://answers.ros.org/users/64484/galaxee/) on 2020-12-02**:
Thanks so much! This is really helpful.